# calling a target from a particular directory

Tags: ant

I have script that call the below target but before calling this target i want that i should be at the following location which is stored in the below variable ..

```
todir="${release.deployment.tool}
```

the target that is called is shownb below..

```
<target name="deploy-ion" description="Used to deploy to a given aaa.">
```

so finally when my target deploy-ion is being called i should make sure that  I should be in 
directory  stored in todir , please advise how to achieve this.

Comment: Just use absolute-path ref with : ${release.deployment.tool} inside your target to perform required tasks won't do the trick?

Comment: @user3584056 can you pls explain in detail as i still not clear what you are trying to explain

Comment: added my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I meant you can use absolute path of your property reference while performing set of tasks inside your target, as by default it uses `basedir` default value as cur-dir or one which is specified at project level at beginning of your build.xml file.

Also alternatively you can use ant's `ant` task : https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ant.html with usage like

`<ant dir="${release.deployment.tool}" target="deploy-ion" />`